# Is there any way I can share apps I develop to my friends before being approved by AppStore?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I am making an app for appstore and I can't wait to share that with my friends. Not exactly done yet and not submitted to appstore yet.

How can my friend use it?

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way is to use TestFlight: [link](http://testflightapp.com)

Remember that you can only register 100 devices on your dev profile.